# PayPal gateway has rejected request Paypal is not supported (#10605: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, paypal-express

I am using two store for my website one is for India and other for global(other country). 
for Global is used paypal payment method. in global store currency is USD, India store currency is INR, Default config currency is USD. When i going to place order using paypal payment method in global store. i got error

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. Currency is not supported (#10605: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details) and redirect to shopping cart page.

But when i set USD currency in all my store India, global and default config and try to place order from global store using paypal payment method then successfully redirect to paypal account.

Comment: is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

I have used small trick to rid this error. It is not good solution but sometime it is useful.

Go to app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Model\Express\Checkout.php. Find the public function start and find below code

```
$this->_api->setAmount($this->_quote->getBaseGrandTotal())
            ->setCurrencyCode($this->_quote->getBaseCurrencyCode())
            ->setInvNum($this->_quote->getReservedOrderId())
            ->setReturnUrl($returnUrl)
            ->setCancelUrl($cancelUrl)
            ->setSolutionType($solutionType)
            ->setPaymentAction($this->_config->paymentAction);

Just replace the below code  

$this->_api->setAmount($this->_quote->getBaseGrandTotal())
            ->setCurrencyCode('USD')
            ->setInvNum($this->_quote->getReservedOrderId())
            ->setReturnUrl($returnUrl)
            ->setCancelUrl($cancelUrl)
            ->setSolutionType($solutionType)
            ->setPaymentAction($this->_config->paymentAction);
```

With this trick now you will go to paypal without any error. But you have to convert the price from Base Currency to USD.

Note: This solution is only for Paypal Express Users.

Code Taken From: http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2016/11/paypal-gateway-has-rejected-request.html