# PayPal gateway has rejected request. Currency is not supported (#10605: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument)

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, paypal-express

PayPal gateway has rejected my request. It gives me following error:

> Currency is not supported (#10605: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details).

I am using `INR` as base currency, and placing order using `AUD`, but I am getting above error.

Please advise any solution for this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

credits : @Boogz

Create a file Config.php in `/app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php`

**Step 1**

Copy the file from `/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php` to `/app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php`

**Step 2**

Look for the `$_supportedCurrencyCodes`

```
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN',
    'NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB');
```

and add your currency that needs supporting, at the end of this array.

I assume `INR` is `Indian Rupee` currency. So your array would look like below, after adding the currency to it.

```
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN',
    'NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB', 'INR');
```

Source : http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/payment/tweak_paypal_standard_for_non-supported_base_currency

Comment: @ BIM : After added country code in $_supportedCurrencyCodes, what is the next step?

Comment: @JeevaRathinam that's all, after that you can try to place an order, it worked for me.....

Comment: what is your base currency

Comment: @JeevaRathinam i am using `INR` as base currency.....

Comment: bro, i am also using base currency INR, but not working, I just add my currency code to     /app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php    like protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN', 'NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB', 'INR');    after i go to place order i get error like,

Comment: my error : PayPal gateway has rejected request. Currency is not supported (#10605: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument)

Comment: after I change my base currency from INR to Dollar, it's working, redirect to PayPal payment portal, but when I use base currency as INR it's not working, I am faced error like,    PayPal gateway has rejected the request. Currency is not supported (#10605: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument)

Comment: Okay, what are all changes you made,

Comment: @JeevaRathinam i made only changes i mentioned in answer....  if you are using `paypal express` , than try [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92527/paypal-gateway-has-rejected-request-paypal-is-not-supported-10605-transaction)

Comment: @JeevaRathinam also check this https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=pCZ3WbvsC8jFuASBhYDYAQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=PayPal+gateway+has+rejected+request.+Currency+is+not+supported+(%2310605:) ,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62780/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-baby-in-magento).